# Finding the intersection(s) of two 3D Polylines

Tags: python, geometry, collision-detection, linear-algebra

I currently have 2 paths generated by a motion planning algorithm in Python. I interpolated into two 3D Polylines with equidistant points. Next I need to find whether these two paths of different lengths intersect (OR even ideally the point(s) at which they get near a certain distance of each other, if any). This is to eventually simulate a collision avoidance algorithm.

After much searching I have found multiple libraries and algorithms that can return points/line intersections of two Polylines, however they are all in 2D. I tried using the Bentley-Ottmann algorithm/python library, the Shapely library, the Geometry3D library, and other 2D solutions found on SO, but none have worked in a 3D environment. Next I tried using a 2D geometry library to find the intersections in the x-y, x-z, and y-z planes individually as shown in the graphs below showing a simple case, but I'm not sure where to go from there or whether that's even the right approach. The Polylines would usually contain 300+ points.

Any help pointing me towards a 3D algorithm or simple adjustments to make to the 2D libraries work in 3D would be really appreciated!
[3D graph view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LZcCa.png), [x-y view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BWHNC.png), [z-y view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZmdC.png).

Comment: In principle, polylines do not intersect in 3D (unless for special reasons), and you are right to think of "a certain distance". But if you set a minimum distance under which an intersection is declared, you don't get points but sections of polylines (think of one polyline inflated to a radius δ and intersected by the other). You might instead consider the point of minimum distance between two segments and check if this distance is smaller than δ. Even with this precaution, you could find several nearby solutions.

Comment: To obtain the minimum distance point between two 3D segments, you can write the parametric equations of the two segments (i.e. P(1-t)+Qt), and minimize the squared distance by cancellation of the gradient. This gives a 2x2 linear system, and if the solutions are not in [0, 1], you saturate the constraints, i.e. set t=0 and t=1.

Comment: If the 2 paths touches doesn't mean that you will have a colision unles it happen at same time.. try to check position in path for every time and check distances